# Add Custom Background Properties to Customizer

Tags: functions, themes, theme-customizer, custom-background

I've just added a second background image upload with the intent of using in the footer:

```
$wp_customize->add_setting(
'tcx_background_image',
array(
    'default'      => '',
    'transport'    => 'postMessage'
)
);

$wp_customize->add_control(
new WP_Customize_Image_Control(
    $wp_customize,
    'tcx_background_image',
    array(
        'label'    => 'Footer Background Image',
        'settings' => 'tcx_background_image',
        'section'  => 'custom_options'
    )
)
);
```

I'm wondering how to include the preset, image position, etc, options?